# Ubuntu isn‘t booting properly after messing around with the graphic drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04, amd-graphics, vulkan

I was trying to get league of legends running on my ubuntu. Therefor I was trying to install [vulkan drivers](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/wiki/Installing-drivers) for my AMD HD7750 graphics card, which - according to wikipedia - is supported by the vulkan drivers. I was doing some more things to the settings according to some guides ok this topic which unfotunately I cant remember exactly. Now when booting the computer I just see my mainboards manufacturer with BIOS option, then I see for a short time this ubuntu-purple (or whatever color that is) background and then just a blackscreen with a flickering every now and then.
I tried going to recovery mode and deleting the vulkan drivers from root shell by executing

```
apt-get remove —auto-remove mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

But I’m atill facing the same issues. Any ideas on how to fix this or should I just format and reinstall ubuntu? (Formatting is not a huge issue since I dont have any important data on that computer)

Answer (score 0):

1. Start up the machine.
2. Hold Shift to bring up GRUB.
3. Pick a recovery option. (Alternatively, sometimes you can press CTRL + ALT + F3 and just go into a terminal).
4. Reverse what you have done.
5. Try the [Oibaf drivers](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers).

> === Basic usage ===
>
> See "Adding this PPA to your system" later on, or just do:
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`
>
> and update your Ubuntu with the package here.
>
> `sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers`

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop (a.k.a GNOME).

1. In order to run the above command press CTRL + ALT + 1. You can replace the 1 with any number from 1-6. Those are different sessions on your computer, CTRL+ALT+7 is the desktop session.
2. login and run

   ```
    sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
   ```

If you are using another desktop you might try to install that as well.

I have gotten myself to a similar situation trying to uninstall vulkan, since my GPU doesn't support it anyway.

!!! Do not run the below !!! I tried removing the vulkan drivers with:

```
    sudo apt autoremove libvulkan1 libvulkan1:i386
```

and this crashed my computer. After restarting, the desktop wouldn't start. I could log in, but not see the desktop, I did check the apt archives inside /var/log/apt/history.log, it turned out that apt decided to go berzerk and uninstall a ton of things. On top of that vulkan itself wasn't uninstalled. If I run the above, saying no of course, there is a huge list of things to uninstall along vulkan.

If you don't have anything fancy, formatting is always an option as you said. Installing gnome again, fixed it for me.